# How to correctly upload an attachment with Apache HTTPClient to RTC (IBM Jazz)?

Tags: java, rest, attachment, rational-team-concert

I am currently facing the following issue with a Java program.

I am trying to upload a file I downloaded from an external server (file type can be different for every execution) to a IBM RTC (or Jazz) server through REST call.

The REST endpoint I am sending the first request (i.e.: the file upload to the central repository) is as the following:

```
https://jazz.host.com:1234/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.workitem.service.internal.rest.IAttachmentRestService/?projectId=<TEAM_AREA_ID>&multiple=true&category=<CATEGORY_ID>
```

And this step works, uploading the file to the central repo. What it is not working is the fact that when the attachment name contains some kind of characters (i.e.: **£**, **ù**, **°**, ...) those are changed into the character **?**.

I am using Apache HttpClient with a CloseableHttpClient, preparing the HttpEntity to be sent as follows:

```
    java.io.File currentAttachmentFile = utils.getFileFromPath(attachmentPath);
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.addBinaryBody("upfile", currentAttachmentFile, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, currentAttachmentFile.getName());
    return builder.build();
```

But even sepcifying the `withCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF8)` to `ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` does not do the trick, the file name stile contains the **?** character (while I expect it to be something like: '**file_name [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665178/send-unicode-characters-via-multipartentity/39919545)!==£$%&^+ù°#@'.png**').

I took a look around for other suggestions but neither those found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718592/encode-filename-in-multipartentitybuilder) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665178/send-unicode-characters-via-multipartentity/39919545) are working for the file name. Moreover, specifying the `Content-Type` to the **POST** call I am sending causes a failure with the message *'Invalid POST request message'* returned by RTC, so this can't be an option.

Through PostMan, the upload with the same file to the same endpoint works so I suppose there is something I am missing when creating the entity to send to RTC.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Best regards,

Alberto

Comment: Have you tried explicitly converting the source filename to UTF-8 encoding prior to uploading?  Something like: `byte[] bytes = currentAttachmentFile.getName().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` and then: `utf8Filename = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`. Then use the `utf8Filename` in your `builder.addBinaryBody` call.

Comment: Hi @j_b , just gave it a try and still i see the file name (once uploaded) with the '?' in place of the above listed chars.